# Cannot join to attribute of basic type

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing this method statement in my repository:

```
Optional<Contract> findFirstByContractDate_YearOrderByContractDateDesc(Integer year);
```

It throws this exception when I run the app:

> org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.BasicPathUsageException: Cannot join to attribute of basic type

Looks like something is not good when getting year from localdatetime. I can implement it in other way (passing begin and end of year and comparing the contractDate) but I'd like to know what's wrong with this.

Comment: Looks like the query is evaluated like (jpql) `... JOIN contractDate.year...` which leads to the above error

Comment: I don't think you can have a Jpa query method filtering a on non-jpa modelized attribute ; ie, I don't think filtering on localdatetime.getYear() is possible. You have to write your @Query and `EXTRACT(YEAR`.

Comment: Pierre is right, you have to write a query. It's not possible to access "components" of a timestamp through the `.` (dot) operator.